# "System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out." errors on Response.write

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-6

I am getting an intermittent "System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out." error when my code hits the line response.write():

```
sMessage = "Searching...0% complete."<br>
sSetVal = "&lt;script>document.getElementById('MessageDiv').innerHTML='" & sMessage & "';&lt;/script>"<br>
Response.write(sSetVal)
```

Note that **Response.BufferOutput = false** is set when the page first starts executing (well before the above code executes).

The code is used to update a progress message while other threads execute long-running processes. One thread runs continuously and checks the status of the other threads. As the other threads finish, this thread outputs updated status messages to the end user. I realise that this could (should) be recoded using ajax, but it is a legacy app and that is not an option at the moment.

This code is run 10,000+ times a day, and the error only occurs about 5 times - so I suspect the response object is being blocked by other threads when the website gets busy. However, I don't know which performance counters to check in the performance monitor. Or is this problem caused by something else? I am using IIS 6, asp.net v2 and vb.net

Comment: Please post the full exception, including all InnerException, by catching the exception and then posting ex.ToString().

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Until now, I have just been using:
<code>
Server.GetLastError().ToString()
</code>
in the Application_Error sub.

and the output for this error has only been<br>
<code>
System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
</code>
All other errors have the full call stack, but not this one. I have added the .InnerException to my error reporting, and I will see what else is reported.

I am have been dumping the current location to the Session object, and then checking it when the error occurs. That is how I know it is failing on the response.write without a full call stack.

Comment: OK - the error has happened again. The inner expception is blank. The only error message is "System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out." from Server.GetLastError().ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `Response.BufferOutput = false` to before the `Response.Write` ?

I would try monitoring the performance counters for memory usage and GC2 collections.

Comment: The statment <b>Response.BufferOutput = false</b> was just to show what the status of the value was - it is set right at the start of the execution. I have also tried Response.BufferOutput = true, then it times out on the next <b>Response.Flush()</b> statement.

Comment: OK, I have moved the Response.BufferOutput = false to make it clearer.